# How to remove a node and subnode in XML based on subnode values using SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I have an XML from an application, I need to remove a Node(ReceiveDeliveryItem) and all its sub Nodes based on a subnode Documentid/id node and LineNumber. For example, I want to delete the   and all its nodes where the Documentid/ID = 13600000493 and Orderref/linenumber = 1. Is there a way to do this with in SQL. Understand how to delete a single node base on a value but not a Node its sub-nodes based on sub-node values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReceiveDelivery xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/file/2" releaseID="9.2">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID>file_incoming</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2023-04-27T16:46:00.893</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>Fileincomingvalue:S00651532:2023-04-27T16:46:00.893</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <connect>
      <TenantID>Production</TenantID>
      <AccountingEntityID>remotesite</AccountingEntityID>
      <Location>remotesite</Location>
      <ActionCriteria>
        <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
      </ActionCriteria>
    </connect>
    <ReceiveDelivery>
      <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
        <DocumentID>
          <ID>S00651532</ID>
        </DocumentID>
        <DocumentDateTime>2023-04-13T15:35:07.9670000</DocumentDateTime>
        <Description>Shiplist - S00651532</Description>
        <Status>
          <Code>Pending</Code>
          <Description>Pending</Description>
          <EffectiveDateTime>2023-04-27T21:46:01.0041398Z</EffectiveDateTime>
        </Status>
        <PackingSlip>S00651532</PackingSlip>
      </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <OrderRef>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="remotesite" lid="mastersite" location="remotesite">13600000493</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </OrderRef>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">5</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR02">S00651532</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR03">1</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <OrderRef>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="remotesite" lid="mastersite" location="remotesite">13600000697</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </OrderRef>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">15</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR02">S00651532</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR03">2</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <OrderRef>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="remotesite" lid="mastersite" location="remotesite">13600000538</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
        </OrderRef>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">4</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>6</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR02">S00651532</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR03">6</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <OrderRef>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="remotesite" lid="mastersite" location="remotesite">13600000654</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </OrderRef>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">1</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>7</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR02">S00651532</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="eam.UDFCHAR03">7</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
    </ReceiveDelivery>
  </DataArea>
</ReceiveDelivery>
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: which database system are you using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-CU1-GDR) (KB5021128) - 13.0.7024.30 (X64)   Dec 24 2022 20:17:51   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: set @myDoc.modify('delete     (/SyncReceiveDelivery/DataArea/ReceiveDelivery//ReceiveDeliveryItem[LineNumber[text()="1"]]
        [PurchaseOrderReference/DocumentID/ID[text()="13600000538"]]
        [PurchaseOrderReference/LineNumber[text()="3"]])')                                                      my root element <myroot comes in with xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2" and the delete does not work if i remove xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2" from my root it works. <myroot xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2">

Comment: how can i remove the xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2" from <my root>?